# JavaFx Application Thread Exception, UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a java application that uses the UI4J library, it works great on my local pc (ubuntu 14.04), but when i create the executable jar and copy it to a virtual machine (also running ubuntu 14.04) i am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libjfxwebkit.so: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
        at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.lambda$static$39(WebPage.java:127)
        at com.sun.webkit.WebPage$$Lambda$66/754904897.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<clinit>(WebPage.java:126)
        at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:824)
        at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:811)
        at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:271)
        at com.ui4j.webkit.WebKitBrowser$WebViewCreator.run(WebKitBrowser.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/826729279.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/571777541.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:77)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:47)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" com.ui4j.api.util.Ui4jException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ui4j.webkit.proxy.WebKitProxy$CallableExecutor.run(WebKitProxy.java:46)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/826729279.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/571777541.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:77)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:47)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ui4j.webkit.browser.WebKitPage.addDocumentListener(WebKitPage.java:180)
        at com.ui4j.webkit.browser.WebKitPage$ByteBuddy$lA15NPlt.addDocumentListener$accessor$YFf7hhha(Unknown Source)
        at com.ui4j.webkit.browser.WebKitPage$ByteBuddy$lA15NPlt$accessor$gnqvWcr9.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ui4j.webkit.proxy.WebKitProxy$CallableExecutor.run(WebKitProxy.java:44)
```

i added javafx-mx.jar file i found on my pc to the exported jar but again the same errors pops up.

The VM is running Oracle's Java8 (not openJava) so JFX should be there and found via the path.

Any ideas?
ilias

Comment: Did you check if the files are there and readable for the user that executes the program?

Comment: Do you have `libxslt1.1` package installed?

Comment: @keuleJ I am not sure if i have the necessary rights to read/execute the libs, i contacted the system admin and asked, but still waiting.

Comment: @Banthar how do i check that? Is there a way to add it to my jar file?

Comment: `dpkg -s libxslt1.1`. If it's missing your admin has to install it. Show them that error - if they manage software installed on that machine, they should know what to do.